# Translate Z Axis location form one object to the Scale (X,Y and Z simultaneously) of another object

Tags: transforms, constraints

I've created an animation that requires the Z Axis location of one object (Empty) to control the scale of another (Circle). I can't seem to get the Transform Constraint to work for this - if anyone can advise on a simple way to do this or point me in the direction of a detailed explanation of the Transform Constraint I'd be grateful.

Comment: why don't you just use a simple driver? if you wanna have a detailed explanation of transform constraint, i would search on yt for a tutorial....

Comment: hello, please make a screenshot of the constraint so that we understand why it fails

Answer (score 4):

As Chris says you could use drivers.

For a *Transformation* constraint, here are the settings you need: Select the *Target* object, enable *Extrapolate*, *Map From > Location* with *Z Min >* -10, *Z Max >* +10 (or whatever values), *Map To > Scale*, *XYZ Source Axis > Z* and *Min >* 0.5 and *Max >* 1.5 (or whatever values):

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was finding it quite difficult to gauge the settings, you've been a great help (and saved me a huge amount of hassle), cheers:-)